# How inefficient is it to create the same publisher multiple times?

Tags: ros, rospy, performance, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm curious about the potential performance hit of creating the same publisher multiple times, for example in a callback:

```
def callback(self, msg):
    publisher = rospy.Publisher(topic, String, queue_size=1)
    self.publisher.publish(msg.data)
```

versus starting the publisher once and storing it:

```
def __init__(self, topic):
    self.publisher = rospy.Publisher(topic, String, queue_size=1)
def callback(self, msg):
    self.publisher.publish(msg.data)
```

I have some code that will publish to (potentially) many topics; creating all the publishers at init may not be worth the additional hassle of bookkeeping if it's just as easy to just create the publishers on an as-needed basis.

For what it's worth, I ran some ipython timing code:

```
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import String
%timeit p = rospy.Publisher('asdf', String, queue_size=10)
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.79 us per loop
```

It doesn't appear that starting the publisher is very expensive performance-wise.

Is there anything else I'm missing that would be a downside of starting the same publisher multiple times?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/219127/how-inefficient-is-it-to-create-the-same-publisher-multiple-times?/) by [Felix Duvallet](https://answers.ros.org/users/22253/felix-duvallet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 539 on 2015-10-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With your first example, using the publisher immediately after it is created will almost certainly result in the published message not actually being published. It takes a nonzero amount of time for the publisher to register itself with the master, but is a non-blocking call.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2015-10-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2